# High memory usage Windows 11

Tags: windows, memory, cpu, windows-11

Yesterday night I opened my laptop and found that the fan was too noisy and my PC was overheated on just the startup! (80C). I still don't know the reason why. Now in the morning, I'm testing out things again.

So now I've opened: Chrome + Spline + VSCode + Mailspring altogether

Here's the current status of my PC:

[Current memory usage (which I think is high)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwzU8.png)

[Usage description in Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRVwk.png)

I have a windows 11 dell laptop with
Intel Core i5 @ 2.40GHz Tiger Lake-U 10nm and 8 GB RAM

And the current temperature is 50 °C as of now. Pretty normal than as of yesterday night

I wanna ask if this high RAM usage is normal? Is everything okay? I'm confused

Comment: "I wanna ask if this high RAM usage is normal?" - Based on your current processes it doesn't seem very high.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. The usage seems to be ok